# Micronaut Reactive Using @Error with ReactorHttpClient

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, micronaut

I have an API with 2 layers Controller and Service with Micronaut, Kotlin & Project Reactor. This application needs to handle requests in non-blocking manner.
I have a Post function `makePayment` method as below

`fun makePayment(payment: Payment): Mono<PaymentDetails>` in class `PaymentController`.

This calls a service class `PaymentService` which also has the same function as above.
This service internally uses `io.micronaut.reactor.http.client.ReactorHttpClient` to make the payment with Bank.

What is the right way to handle exception here?

**Option1**

```
reactorHttpClient.exchange().onErrorResume()
```

In `onErrorResume` I will map it to custom error code with suitable HTTP Status.No other specific Global Error handling is done.

**Option2**
Uses Controller Advise approach to have a Global Exception Handler with `@Error(global = true)` as mentioned below.
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#globalErrorHandling

I tried both approaches and both works.
I would like to understand what is the right approach considering **Non-Blocking server and reactive streams** approach.
Also does the Global Exception Handler with `@Error(global = true)` going to work like a **Blocking** or **Non-Blocking** way?

Comment: Option #3: Custom implementation of `ErrorResponseProcessor` and a custom error DTO. BTW, you may simplify your code by using a declarative client, they too can return reactive types. BR

Comment: Thank You for the input. I mostly see the reactive onError used during project reactor code as that's how reactive streams handle errors. In micronaut context of handling error using @Error , is it a blocking approach? or still can I use that in a reactive context?